# Update table record using PHP AJAX when multiple instances

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

On my page I have multiple forms all the same as this...

```
<form class='bill-upd'>
   <input type='hidden' value='".$info['rand']."' name='rand2' id='rand2'>
   <input type='hidden' value='".$info['id']."' name='billid' id='billid'>
   Total <input type='text' id='total' name='total' /><br />
   Bill name<input type='text' id='bill-name' name='bill-name' /><br />
   bill descriptiion <input type='text' id='bill-description' name='bill-description' /><br />
   bill colour<input type='text' id='bill-colour' name='bill-colour' />
   <input type='button' value='submit' onClick='updateBill();' />
</form>
```

I then have my AJAX as so

```
function updateBill()
{
    $.post('update_bill.php', $('.bill-upd').serialize(), 
        function(data) {
        $(this).append(data);
    });
};
```

If I have one form on my page, this works fine, but when there are multiple instances, my same record is being overwritten, can anybody tell me where im going wrong?

Thanks

---

With the help of @Armatus and @Bricriu I got it sorted, the answer as marked worked, stupidly forgot to wrap it within document.ready

Comment: Are you printing `$info['id']` in a loop where `$info` will be different every iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a way to specify which bill you're updating, otherwise it just takes all of them. This should work, since we can determine which one it is by which button was clicked.

Edit: I personally would bind the even using jQuery rather than onClick on the element itself:

```
$(".bill-upd input:submit").click(function(){
    var elem = $(this);
    $.post('update_bill.php', elem.parent('.bill-upd').serialize(), 
        function(data) {
        elem.append(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @bricriu , doesn't seem to work however, I dont receive any error and firebug says its posted the data but it doesnt actually update...

Comment: Oh right. It's because of scope issues with $(this). I will edit.

Comment: Sorry, I realized my mistake right after hitting submit... Edited again. I would do the above and replace the updateBill() function.

Comment: Still nothing! so frustrating, I'm not receiving any console errors neither @bricriu

Comment: Oh sorry, your button is not a submit type. I would add a class to that button (maybe 'submit' or 'update', and you can select it that way.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10351/discussion-between-bricriu-and-liam)

Answer (score 0):

If the other forms have the  same class `.bill-upd` the javascript `.serlialize()` will take values from them also. Make sure the other forms have an alternate class.

What would be better would be if you gave the form a unique id such as `id="billform"` and then replace `$('.bill-upd').serialize()` with `$('#billform').serialize()`.

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

Use this:

```
$(this).parent('.bill-upd').serialize()
```

to serialize the parent of that which was clicked.

Comment: Initially I did have them as ID's but still couldnt get it to work with multiple instances of the form on the page....

Comment: Is it multiple instances of the same form?

Comment: Do all forms have the same class? `class='bill-upd'`

Comment: Ok. Because they have the same class, the .serialize function will not be effective. It should only have to serialize one form. Since all your forms have the same class it either does not know which form to serialize or it takes the values of the one it serialized most recently. Therefore do not have the same class on all of them.

Comment: May be a bit of a weird solution, but could I add a class to the form on submit such as 'active' then run the AJAX and get all values from the 'active' form?

Comment: Just saw @bricriu comment, same thing :)

Comment: Thanks @gimg1, no luck however

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your PHP script?